phpmyadmin showing 500 error in Ubuntu 24.04 lts after upgrade
i had updated ubuntu 22.04 -- >> 24.04
now getting this error while phpmyadmin getting not loaded into browser

Mon Sep 23 18:30:18.060029 2024] [php:error] [pid 11672] [client 192.168.1.150:54278] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: PhpMyAdmin\\Menu::__construct(): Argument #1 ($dbi) must be of type PhpMyAdmin\\DatabaseInterface, null given, called in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Header.php on line 114 and defined in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Menu.php:57\nStack trace:\n#0 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Header.php(114): PhpMyAdmin\\Menu->__construct()\n#1 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/ResponseRenderer.php(168): PhpMyAdmin\\Header->__construct()\n#2 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/ResponseRenderer.php(199): PhpMyAdmin\\ResponseRenderer->__construct()\n#3 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/ErrorHandler.php(335): PhpMyAdmin\\ResponseRenderer::getInstance()\n#4 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/ErrorHandler.php(307): PhpMyAdmin\\ErrorHandler->dispFatalError()\n#5 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/ErrorHandler.php(237): PhpMyAdmin\\ErrorHandler->addError()\n#6 [internal function]: PhpMyAdmin\\ErrorHandler->handleException()\n#7 {main}\n  thrown in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Menu.php on line 57
[Mon Sep 23 18:30:18.060184 2024] [php:error] [pid 11672] [client 192.168.1.150:54278] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getDisplay() on null in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/ResponseRenderer.php:293\nStack trace:\n#0 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/ResponseRenderer.php(411): PhpMyAdmin\\ResponseRenderer->getDisplay()\n#1 [internal function]: PhpMyAdmin\\ResponseRenderer->response()\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/ResponseRenderer.php on line 293

tried all measures finding it online.
Earlier we were using php7.4 now we have set php8.3 (so when php7.4 was not allowing even to load the website) but PHP v8.3 atleast allowing us to connect to site and load it in browser (Since this is updated)
but when we do http://192.168.1.100/phpmyadmin/ (or localhost/phpmyadmin)
This page isn’t working
192.168.1.100 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
Can someone help us?

I have not yet updated my phpmyadmin server to 24.04 but I have had same or similar errors with it when updating to previous Ubuntu versions. Try the following:

If you have not already got it installed, install the php mbstring package:

sudo apt-get install php8.3-mbstring

You have not said which web server you are using but assuming Apache then check which php module your apache is using:

a2query -m |grep php
If that does not list your installed php version e.g. php8.3 then you may need to disable whatever php module it is using and enable the correct one for example say it listed php8.1 then:
sudo a2dismod php8.1
sudo a2enmod php8.3

Thanks, it resolved my problem at moment
